# Pass 2 params to vuex action from array

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I need to pass 2 params to my action in store:

```
<tr v-for="printer in printers" :key="printer.id" >
   <td>
      <p >{{printer.name}}</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div v-for="preparation_area in preparation_areas" :key="preparation_area.id">
         <button class="primary-light inline"  @click="setPreparationAreaPrinter(printer, preparation_area)">{{preparation_area.name}}</button>
      </div>
   </td>
</tr>
```

store:

```
setPreparationAreaPrinter ({commit}, printer, preparation_area) {
  axios.patch('/preparation_areas/' + preparation_area.id, {
    printer: printer.id,
  })
 .then((response) => {  
.....
  });
}
```

printer.id works and assigns correct printer name, but preparation_area is undenified. What is the correct way to implement it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your parameters in a payload object

```
    setPreparationAreaPrinter ({ commit }, payload){
        axios.patch('/preparation_areas/' + payload.preparation_area.id, {
        printer: payload.printer.id,
    }).then((response) => {...});
    }
```

And reflect it in your click listener:
`@click="setPreparationAreaPrinter({printer, preparation_area})"`

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can only pass 1 parameter, so if you need to pass more than 1 use an array.  An array qualifies as 1 parameter.  Then you can access each parameter in the action via data[0] and data[1]

store.dispatch('setSplitData',[data[0], data [1]])

// in the action:
setSplitData (context, [data1, data2]) { // uses ES6 argument destructuring

//...or with an object:
store.dispatch('setSplitData',{ 
  data1: data[0], 
  data2: data [1],
})

Comment: Could you give some code example? The alternative solution I see is to create another method on the button that sets something like currentPrepararationArea. But I was wondering if there was something more concise.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using this approach as you have to remember the index of the properties you want to access. Its better to use objects for this.